# Why does Bisq claim that my earliest receive address has been used in 10 transactions?

Tags: bisq

In the "Funds" tab, in the "Receive funds" sub-tab, there's a long list of unused receive addresses (as expected). In the bottom, there's a bunch of ones saying "Used in 1 transaction(s)", again as expected...

But in the very bottom, there's one that stands out by saying "Used in 10 transaction(s)".

This makes me worried and anxious. Why was this not only reused, but reused nine times? I never did anything differently from how I trade/use Bisq today. That receive address must have been created when I created my Bisq wallet in early 2018.

Can somebody explain what the deal is with this? Has Bisq for some reason reused the same address and thus broken my blockchain privacy? Was it some kind of bug? Misunderstanding by me somehow?

Answer (score 1):

> **Was it some kind of bug?**

Yes, so it seems.

---

See https://bisq.community/t/privacy-address-reuse/5899

> torte
> 1 Aug '18
>
> When looking into my bisq account under
> funds --> Receive funds
> I see that usually new addresses are used. But on the bottom there is one address 1A… used already more than a dozen times and I wonder why

...

> ManfredKarrer
> Founder
> Aug '18
>
> Do you have the latest version? If there is a reuse of old addresses it is a bug. In older versions there was a bug with that but it should have been fixed a while back.

...

> torte
> Aug '18
>
> Upgraded to version 7.1 and did the same type of transaction where I saw the address reuse before. This time no address was reused, so everything worked fine.
> Great job, thanks to the team!
> As well I’m pleased that I can manage the addresses in the wallet one by one (as far as I know not a new feature but a good one for privacy reasons).

---

The [release notes for version 0.7.1](https://github.com/bisq-network/bisq/releases?after=v0.8.1) on  4 Jul 2018  say

> - [Fix reuse of change addresses](https://github.com/bisq-network/bisq-core/pull/113)

Which refers to [Issue 1540](https://github.com/bisq-network/bisq/issues/1540)

> the first address generated by the HD wallet gets reused repeatedly, other addresses were used, only once per address, but these are clustered around the first address (e.g. with oxt.me) , allowing transactions to be linked. this also discloses disclosing balances etc to counterparties who may have personally identifying information due to the nature of the transfers